# How to request client cookies on server ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, cookies

I have a javascript function that updates a cookie in the following manner:

aspx page:

```
function setCookie()
{
    //...
    document.cookie = "myCookie = HelloWorld";
    //...
}
```

After an asp control triggers an event, the entire page gets sent back from the client. I want to be able to read the value of my cookie. How do I do that?

I've tried:

`string temp = Request.ServerVariables["myCookie"].ToString();` but that is the wrong way to do it.

How do I read the client cookie on the server

Comment: You should just read up on cookies in asp.net. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Request.Cookies["userName"] != null)
    Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["userName"].Value);
```

[Source MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.ASPX)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the helper method to retrieve cookie at server side.

```
public static String GetCookie(String cookieName)
{
   try
   {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName] == null)
         return String.Empty;

      return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName].Value;
   }
   catch
   {
      return String.Empty;
   }
}
```

### Usage

```
var result = GetCookie("myCookie");
```

If you want to set cookie at client side, look at this [Cookie plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/trunk/plugins/cookie/jquery.cookie.js?r=6125).